# Jboss server error : why it cause

Tags: java, jboss

why the error occurs when i am starting the jboss server 6.0 ?
'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Bozho: it looks like the error is coming from the batch script that launches JBoss.  There's no stacktrace to give because the JVM hasn't even been started at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your PATH environment variable hasn't been set up correctly.  Does this link help?

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/FindstrCommandNotFound

**EDIT**: are you sure that the JBoss startup batch script (usually in `%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\run.bat`) is picking up the PATH correctly?  It might be running as a different user with a different PATH.  Edit this script and add the line `echo %PATH%` before the first line that contains `findstr`.  What output does this give you?

The only other place `findstr` is used (in jboss-6.0.0.20100721-M4 anyway) is in the `service.bat` script in the same folder as `run.bat` .  Again, you could try putting `echo %PATH%` before the line in this script that uses `findstr` if the previous step didn't help you.

**EDIT 2**: according to your comments, the `echo %PATH%` line I asked you to add gave the following output:

```
E:\jdk1.6\bin;E:\apache-ant-1.7.0\bin;E:\jboss-6.0\bin\run.bat
```

Clearly this doesn't contain `C:\WINDOWS\system32`, so JBoss definitely won't be able to find `findstr`.  But I don't understand why the PATH is ending up like this.  How are you starting JBoss - as a service or by running `run.bat`?  Is JBoss being run under some user account which has been set up with a very restricted PATH?  Do you have some other script which is manipulating the PATH before JBoss starts?  Also, which version of Windows are you using?

Also, it's not immediately clear to me from your three comments

- I'm already checked that the findstr application is already in that path C:\WINDOWS\system32\
- E:\jboss-6.0\bin\run.bat
- Am also set that in the system variables in Environmental Variables

whether `C:\WINDOWS\system32` is in the PATH in Control Panel > System > Environment Variables.  Is `C:\WINDOWS\system32` in the PATH in the System Variables section within the Environment Variables dialog?

This doesn't seem to be an issue with JBoss.  This seems to be more of an issue with the environment within which you are running it.  I can quite imagine a lot of other programs would be unhappy with being run in a similar environment.

Comment: I'm already checked that the findstr application is already in that path
C:\WINDOWS\system32\

Comment: Am also set that in the system variables in Environmental Variables.

Comment: But there is no change. Am using your echo %path% ..the result is

Comment: E:\jdk1.6\bin;E:\apache-ant-1.7.0\bin;E:\jboss-6.0\bin\run.bat

Comment: For ur patience ,i really thank you first.
1.AM running the jboss 1.6.0  through netbeans6.8.
2.i'm using the user account for windows only.
3.version : windows 7.0

In My comments
1.C:\WINDOWS\system32 in the PATH in the System Variables section within the Environment Variables.

Am using the netbeans 6.8,the error occurs in this way
I have an another option to start the jboss through start the run.bat in bin folder.

Comment: @AdalArasan: I have to admit I haven't used NetBeans much.  Nonetheless, I downloaded the latest version (6.9.1) and tried to add a JBoss 6 server to it using Tools > Servers, but was unable to.  NetBeans apparently doesn't support JBoss 6 (http://netbeans.org/community/releases/69/relnotes.html), only JBoss versions 4 and 5.  How are you starting JBoss 6 through NetBeans?